# Copy bluetooth paired devices from one phone to another

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-pairing

I bought a new Android phone and was able to transfer all my data, sms, call log, etc to it.

My question is how can I transfer the list of all paired bluetooth devices from my old phone to the new one so that I won't need to pair my new phone with my bluetooth devices again?

Is this even possible given that each phone has a unique bluetooth mac address?

Comment: I really want to know this too...  and/or how this perhaps can be done at the code level (as opposed to system level or using an app)

Comment: i need a workaround too